# Is it possible to do panorama Image Stitching in Android from Java?

Tags: java, android, opencv, panoramas, image-stitching

I am using openCV4Android and I know there are lots of questions related with this topic. Most of them (the ones with answer), suggest a solution with C++ and add it to the project in the folder jni + Android.mk, etc.

Can I do something to avoid C++ and call every method from Java?

If it is not possible with OpenCV, I am open to try alternatives.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a [JavaCV](http://code.google.com/p/javacv/) - Java interface to the OpenCV library, it is popular for the Android application.

Comment: Actually OpenCV has lots of methods in Java (Imgproc...) but I don't find any for ImageStitching. So I am going to try JavaCV. If you know any good tutorial for panoramas  with it, please, tell me. Meanwhile, I will google for it.

Comment: http://code.google.com/p/javacv/source/browse/src/main/java/com/googlecode/javacv/cpp/opencv_stitching.java?r=a1f204f9cf107e00b556a235ede8552e4cbd1f9c

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use JNI NDK for stitching if you want to do stitching with opencv