# cannot resolve symbol BufferedImage

Tags: java, android

I'm trying to follow the tutorial here https://boofcv.org/index.php?title=Example_Image_Stitching to test how it works on Android.

after copying and pasting the example code I got errors saying cannot resolve symbol BufferedImage and Graphics2D. I tried googling to find the correct jar but found people were saying the jar isn't available because it is native code. then how does this example work?

Thanks

Comment: Not sure this needed a downvote (whoever did it); the cut-down nature of the Android java implementation is sometime very annoying and obtuse.

Answer (score 1):

BufferedImage can not be used in Android. For image stitching in Android, you need to use OpenCV or you can use JavaCV.

You can check below links:
https://ramsrigoutham.com/2012/12/21/panorama-app-on-android-using-stitching-module-opencv/

[Is it possible to do panorama Image Stitching in Android from Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19977093/is-it-possible-to-do-panorama-image-stitching-in-android-from-java)

[Image stitching in android using OpenCV](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15492259/image-stitching-in-android-using-opencv)

Answer (score 0):

Android has a subset of the standard Java libraries. BufferedImage is not included.

Comment: btu where can i find the jar? i can see the parent class of the example i'm referring to imports java.awt.image

Comment: It's part of awt which is not in Android. You need to use other methods; Bitmap is the Android equivalent but deeply underpowered for image tiling (of very large images).

Comment: ok..i dont understand why that example would work. I guess i'm out of luck to implement it in android

Comment: It's *possible* BoofCV does not use AWT (I have not looked), but the example code does use AWT. It may be worth asking the BoofCV people about Android support, then adapting the code to use a Bitmap

Comment: Fwiw, you can do tiling with the various Bitmap methods (there's one that loads part of an image from file),  it just won't perform as fast as native c code.

Answer (score 0):

It's not "native code", but it is only included in the Java SE  AWT package, which is not part of the Android SDK

Bitmap is an equivalent class

A Canvas would be similar to the Graphics2D

Comment: btu where can i find the jar? i can see the parent class of the example i'm referring to imports java.awt.image

Comment: `java.awt` is not available on Android. I don't know why you think you need a JAR or that one exists for what you're attempting to do. You need a different way to stitch images in Android.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6344654/how-to-add-java-awt-image-package-in-android

Comment: yea...thats what i dont understand why that example works if java.awt isn't available.

Comment: i can't find other way to stitch images...after weeks of googling. that example seems to be my last hope

Comment: Then build a Java web service externally to your Android app that has access to the BufferedImage class

Comment: cant...this app is ideally for local use which shouldnt require internet connection :(

Comment: I've found several posts about stitching Bitmap in Android

Comment: yea...trust me. ive gone through 100+ those posts on how to stitch images in Android but no luck at all. i guess i'm too weak

Comment: Perhaps you should make a question about the problems with those attempts than ask for something not possible?

Comment: yea i did. i also started bounty, but no one has the answer

Comment: It is part of AWT, not Swing.

Comment: @EJP oops, yes.